# How can I resolve a Micronaut Controller method by a URI Template and HttpMethod?

Tags: java, micronaut

I have a question regarding Micronaut and REST APIs. Let me explain first my case and what I am trying to achieve.

Let's pretend there are two REST resource `person` and `address`. `address` is a subresource of `person` resource and therefore the URI path would be as follows.

`/persons/{person-id}/addresses/{address-id}`

For our REST clients I would like to provide a feature I call *"Expanded Gets"* similar to table joins in SQL.

**Without** *"Expanded Gets"* a client has to execute at least two HTTP calls to read a person and its addresses.

- `/persons/123` - to read the person
- `/persons/123/addresses/` - to read all addresses for that person

**With** *"Expanded Gets"* a client can read the person and its addresses in only one request.

- `/persons/123?expands=(addresses)`

So far the intro part.

In order to implement this in Micronaut I was thinking about registering a HTTP filter that does

1. Reads the result of the `PersonController`
2. If the `expands` parameter is in the querystring the it should resolve the uri template of the `addresses` subresource
3. with the uri template it should tell Micronaut to resolve the corresponding controller bean method.
4. invoke the method and combine the person & addresses in the response body

It tried to implement some of the filter as you can see below.

My questions now are:

- Is there a way in Micronaut to resolve a controller bean and method by an `UriTemplate` and a `HttpMethod`?
- How can I invoke this method?

---

*Pseudo Implementation*

```
@Filter("/v1/**")
public class HateoasFilter implements HttpServerFilter {


  @Override
  public Publisher<MutableHttpResponse<?>> doFilter(
    HttpRequest<?> request, ServerFilterChain chain) {
    return Flowable.fromPublisher(chain.proceed(request)).doOnNext((res) -> {

      // if the request contains a expands parameter in the querystring
      if (!request.getParameters().getAll("expands").isEmpty()) {

        // get the person
        Person person = res.body();

        String expands = request.getParameters().getFirst("expands").get();

        // lookup the uri path. address => /person/{personId}/addresses/. This is part of the application and not Micronaut.
        String uriPathForSubresource = subresourceRegistry.lookup("addresses");

        UriTemplate subresourceUriTemplate = UriTemplate.of(uriPathForSubresource);

        // how can I lookup the controller bean and GET method for a uri template?
        Method m = micronaut.lookupMethod(subresourceUriTemplate, HttpMethod.GET);

        // invoke the controller method and the the addresses
        List<Address> addresses = m.invoke(....);

        // put em to the body
        res.body(new PersonAddresses(person, addresses))
      }

    });
  }
}
```

I'm new to Micronaut and I would be glad if anyone of you could give me hints on how I could implement that feature. Thank you.